# Condition in Mysql while selecting data form different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this code and it was working perfectly, but I have added two new columns in my `orders` table in my database:

- `guest_user ('Y'/'N'`)
- `guest_phone`

What I want to do is if `guest_user` is `'y'` then I don't have `users.email` so replace it with `orders.guest_phone`.

How to do this. Can anyone fix it please....

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    orders.id AS 'Order Id',
    users.email AS 'Email',
    orders.price AS 'Amount',
    orders.city_sj AS 'City',
    orders.order_from AS 'Web/App',
    orders.payment_status AS 'COD/PWC',
    orders. AT AS 'Date and Time'

FROM users, orders, order_history    

WHERE users.id = order_history.uid
  AND orders.id = order_history.oid
  AND orders. REAL = 1
  AND orders.price > 1
  AND orders. STATUS = 1
ORDER BY orders.id;
```

Running the above code i am getting the below type of Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBkUw.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the job you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.id as 'Order Id',  
       IF(orders.guest_user = 'Y', orders.guest_phone, users.email) as 'Phone/Email',  
       orders.price as 'Amount', orders.city_sj as 'City',
       orders.order_from as 'Web/App', 
       orders.payment_status as 'COD/PWC', 
       orders.at as 'Date and Time'
FROM users
JOIN order_history ON users.id = order_history.uid  
JOIN orders ON orders.id= order_history.oid
WHERE orders.real=1 AND orders.price>1 AND orders.status=1
ORDER BY orders.id;
```

You should also use *explicit* join syntax instead of old style *implicit* style.

Comment: Respected Sir, the guest_user field is in orders table not in users table. The above code didn't work. when i change the users.gest_user into orders.guest_user. can you help please?

Comment: @bc120200427SaleemJafar Just replace `users.` with `orders.`. Please check the edit I made and let me know how it executes on your platform.

Comment: @bc120200427SaleemJafar Can you post some sample data in order to better describe the problem you are facing?

Comment: Sir, kindly loot into my question. I have upload a pic of the out sample of my data. when the orders.guest_user='Y' it does not git those data